# Oracle SQL Query to lists the companies that work at least in all the domains that company with id 1 works in

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL Query to lists the companies that work at least in all the domains that company with id 1 works in.

and answer should be id= 3 and 7
because 1, 3 and 7 are using domains Education and Energy

```
CREATE TABLE Company_Domain (id NUMBER, Domain_Name VARCHAR(30));

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Company_Domain VALUES (1 , 'Education');
  INSERT INTO Company_Domain VALUES (1 , 'Energy');
  INSERT INTO Company_Domain VALUES (2 , 'IT');
  INSERT INTO Company_Domain VALUES (2 , 'Marketing');
  INSERT INTO Company_Domain VALUES (3 , 'Energy');
  INSERT INTO Company_Domain VALUES (3 , 'Education');
  INSERT INTO Company_Domain VALUES (4 , 'Food');
  INSERT INTO Company_Domain VALUES (4 , 'Energy');
  INSERT INTO Company_Domain VALUES (5 , 'Marketing');
  INSERT INTO Company_Domain VALUES (5 , 'Law');
  INSERT INTO Company_Domain VALUES (6 , 'IT');
  INSERT INTO Company_Domain VALUES (6 , 'Banking');
  INSERT INTO Company_Domain VALUES (7 , 'Education');
  INSERT INTO Company_Domain VALUES (7 , 'Energy');
  INSERT INTO Company_Domain VALUES (8 , 'Marketing');
  INSERT INTO Company_Domain VALUES (8 , 'IT');
END;
/
```

| id | Domain_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Education |
| 1 | Energy |
| 2 | IT |
| 2 | Marketing |
| 3 | Energy |
| 3 | Education |
| 4 | Food |
| 4 | Energy |
| 5 | Marketing |
| 5 | Law |
| 6 | IT |
| 6 | Banking |
| 7 | Education |
| 7 | Energy |
| 8 | Marketing |
| 8 | IT |

regards

Answer (score 0):

Select:

```
select id
from company_domain
where domain_name
  in (select domain_name from company_domain where id = 1)
  and id <> 1
group by id
having count(domain_name)
  = (select count(domain_name) from company_domain where id = 1);
```

Output:

| ID |
| --- |
| 7 |
| 3 |

Rows in the table Company_name must be unique.